# Can anyone explain what is the default interface implementation in C# 8.0?

Tags: c#, default-interface-member

I’m quite new to C# 8.0 and I want to know what is the default interface implementation?

Comment: [Here you go](https://www.google.com/search?q=default+interface+implementation+c%23)

Comment: [Here's the Microsoft Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/) for this feature. Essentially, instead of implementers needing to implement all members of the interface, you can have a default implementation for members, which the implementers don't have to override.

Comment: Read this: [How I Learned to Love Default Implementations in C# 8.0](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/01/10/default-implementation-csharp)

Comment: The description of the `default-interface-member` tag offers a far better answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Default implementations is a feature in C# 8.0 that an interface member can now be specified with a code body, and if an implementing class or struct does not provide an implementation of that member, no error occurs. Instead, the default implementation is used.

Read more here: [Default Interface Implementation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/)